# clojure: elegant mocking of functions with different values

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

While writing unit tests I have to sometimes mock a function to return a sequence of defined values for each function call.

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
(testing "fitness-proportionate selection"
  ; store sequence of rand values in atom, first val is ignored as we always use rest
  ; normalized fitness: 0: 0 1: 1/6 2: 1/3 3: 1/2
  ; summed fitness 0: 0 1: 1/6 2: 1/2 3: 1
  (let [r (atom [0 1 1/2 1/6 0])] (with-redefs [rand (fn [] (first (swap! r rest)))]
    (is (= [3 2 1 0] (fitness-proportionate-selection [0 1 2 3] identity))))))
```

Can somebody help me to find a more elegant way to do this?
Something that is more readable, and contains less logic.
Which would result in less errors in the unit tests itself.
I am currently using `clojure.test` and would prefer to not use an additional library.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't think of an alternate way of mocking the `rand` function aside from having some kind of reference holding the sequence of values it should return. This makes sense since `rand` is itself a function that generates its values from some other (pseudo-random) source.

That said, I would create a higher-order function that returns a number generator based on a sequence of numbers, instead of embedding that logic in the test code.

```
(defn gen-rand
  "Returns a no args function that mocks `rand`,
  which returns on each call a number from s in 
  the same order provided."
  [s]
  (let [x (atom s)]
    #(let [n (first @x)] 
       (swap! x rest)
       n)))

(defn fitness-proportionate-selection
  "Mock function."
  [s f]
  (vec (repeatedly 4 rand)))

(testing "fitness-proportionate selection"
  (with-redefs [rand (gen-rand [1 1/2 1/6 0])]
    (is (= [1 1/2 1/6 0] (fitness-proportionate-selection [0 1 2 3] identity)))))
```

Note that I changed the code so that *all* values in the sequence provided to `gen-rand` are returned and the first one is not discarded.

Comment: This is a nice solution. I think it's worth pointing out that the `gen-rand` function as written above allows you to mock any 0-arity functions to return a sequence of values in order, and with a simple tweak, it could mock functions of any arity. Makes for a nice helper function in tests.